# How does the warlock's Eyes of the Rune Keeper eldritch invocation interact with typos?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations

Would the Warlock's Eyes of the Rune Keeper eldritch invocation, along with other magic effects that enable you to read languages, allow misspelt/miswritten words to be understood?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 12):

### It is not quite specific, but likely you would understand it as well as you would your own languages

All the feature Eyes of the Rune Keeper says is:

> You can read all writing.

Seemingly this provides you with one aspect of the trinity of language understanding (read, write, and speak) meaning if the typo could be understood if you knew the language, you could understand the message thanks to the Invocation.